# Python: default argument values vs global variables

Tags: python, function, arguments

I saw this default values usage in the Python's [Queue](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/Queue.py) module:

```
def _put(self, item, heappush=heapq.heappush):
    heappush(self.queue, item)

def _get(self, heappop=heapq.heappop):
    return heappop(self.queue)
```

I wonder why the variables are used as function arguments here? Is it just a matter of taste or some kind of optimization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a micro optimization. Default values are evaluated only once at function definition time, and locals (including parameters) are a bit faster to access than globals, they're implemented as a C array lookup instead of a `dict` lookup. It also allows avoiding repeatedly looking up the `heappush` and `heappop` members of `heapq`, without polluting the namespace by pulling them in directly.

Timeit snippets:

```
python -mtimeit --setup "import heapq" --setup "def f(q,x,p=heapq.heappush): p(q,x)" "f([], 1)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.538 usec per loop

python -mtimeit --setup "import heapq" --setup "def f(q,p=heapq.heappop): p(q)" "f([1])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.386 usec per loop

python -mtimeit --setup "import heapq" --setup "def f(q,x): heapq.heappush(q,x)" "f([], 1)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.631 usec per loop

python -mtimeit --setup "import heapq" --setup "def f(q): heapq.heappop(q)" "f([1])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.52 usec per loop
```

Comment: Can you give a reference for the array lookup?

Comment: +1, it saves a few nanoseconds in Py2.7 on my box. Note that the current tip does import the heap functions into its namespace: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/queue.py

Comment: @ramcdougal For being faster: [1](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Local_Variables) For being an array lookup: First, `dis` shows that local and global names use different bytecode operations (`LOAD_GLOBAL` vs `LOAD_FAST`). Second, digging through [ceval.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/ceval.c) will show that `LOAD_FAST` is mapped to `GETLOCAL` which is a macro defined earlier in the same file which expands to `fastlocals[i]` which is a dynamically allocated array in the various functions in ceval.c that perform interpretation.